# Number of events within each elevation class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.3, spatial-statistics

I'm trying to model how elevation affects fire events for an AOI, I have run my cluster analysis for the fire events and right now I'm trying to calculate how many fire events fall within each elevation class.
I have used the zonal histogram tool in ArcGIS, but I'm not sure I trust the output. Is there a better tool for which to achieve this?

Comment: Zonal statistics is a good tool to use for such problems. Are your fire events points or polygons? this affects the choice and procedure of your analysis. Also please update the question with the type of software you are using

Comment: Points features.

Comment: and the software you are using?, I assume it is ArcGIS, it is just that the appropriate version is tagged

Comment: @yanes yeah it's ArcGIS 10.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use ArcGIS.

You can extract the elevation value for each point using "extract value to points". You can then work on the attribute tabe to create your categories (field calculator with a linear transformation, e.g. !field!/10), then you summarize the table to have the count of event.

As a remark, zonal histogram should work fine but you need to set up the raster analysis environment to make sure that the cell size for the anlysis is the same as your DEM.